# How to make an insert from the multivalue parameter resultset in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I can't get a multivalue parameter query report to execute. I need to make an `INSERT` of the resultset from what has been filtered out. So, I have a dataset that makes an insert from the multivalue parameter sproc. The `@multivalue` parameter result shreds out column1, column2, column3 and are meant to be derived from the stored procedure dataset and column4 from the selection from table2, Something like...

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4")
    SELECT "@multivalue", "column4"
    FROM "table2"
```

Okay , I get part of this to work. The Ínsert dataset functioning if I'm setting a hardcoded value in my set@Multivalue ='00-00200-002' But I need this to be the result of the stored procedure query.

```
declare @MultiVal nvarchar(max)
set @MultiVal= N'**RESULT OF @MultiVal GOES HERE**'
insert into TABLE (column1,column2,column3,column4)
EXEC sproc @MultiVal
```

Thanks Unfgiv. I'm using a split function that shreds the @MultiVal into 4 columns and using the =JOIN... I would appreciate though if could elaborate more on your idea, I'm little bit slow after the last two days, working on this thing. It seems though that I should be able to do something like this,

```
declare @MultiVal nvarchar(max) 
,@result nvarchar(max) 
set @MultiVal=@result 
insert into table (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) 
Values (@result= 'EXEC storedprocedure @MultiVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can map a multi-value SSRS parameter to different Stored Procedure parameters like that. I think you would need to split your multi-valued parameter into boolean fields (if you only have 4 as specified) that would determine if the value should be passed.

The other, more robust, option would be to join the selected values in your multi-value parameter together, pass them into the sproc as one value, then parse them back out with a cursor (typically slow, but for this it should be ok)

You can join your selected values together by using the following code in SSRS...

```
JOIN(Parameters!MultiValParam.Value, ",")
```

swap out the "**,**" with delim of choice